# Print structure of a folder with recursive function Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to print a structure of a folder with shell script. So it would look like this

```
File : linux -3.14/COPYING
File : linux -3.14/CREDITS
   Directory : linux -3.14/Documentation
      File : linux -3.14/Documentation/00 - INDEX
      Directory : linux -3.14/Documentation/ABI
         File : linux -3.14/Documentation/ABI/README
```

and this is my script. The problem is that it prints out all files and folders for the current directory but it will not print for the subfolders. Maybe I do recursion wrong

```
dirPrint() {
    # Find all files and print them first
    file=$1
    for f in $(ls ${file}); do
        if [ -f ${f} ]; 
            then
                path="$(pwd)/$f"
                echo "File: $path"
        fi
    done

    # Find all directories and print them
    for f in $(ls ${file}); do
        if [ -d ${f} ];
            then
                path="$(pwd)/$f"
                echo "Directory: $path"
                echo "  $(dirPrint "$path")"
        fi
    done
}
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    dirPrint .
else
    dirPrint "$1"
fi
```

And also what is the difference between using $1, "$1" and "${1}"?

Comment: My kubuntu don't have `tree` command. This is an exercise so i don't know if my tutor has `tree` command in their linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various problems in your script. You shouldn't parse the output of `ls`, iterate over the expansion of a wildcard instead. Always double quote the variables to prevent spaces in filenames from breaking your commands.

```
#! /bin/bash
dir_find () {
    local dir=$1
    local indent=$2
    for f in "$dir"/* ; do
        printf '%s%s\n' "$indent${f##*/}"
        if [[ -d $f ]] ; then
            dir_find "$f" "    $indent"
        fi
    done
}

dir_find .
```

Comment: Thank you. And what's meaning of using `[[]]` here? What is indent?

Comment: It's a more modern version of `[]` that exists in bash. See `man bash` for help.

Comment: `[[ -d $f ]]` returns true if `$f` is a directory.

Comment: What is indent short for?

Comment: $indent stores spaces for indentation.

Comment: i tried. Everything works find. But indent variable seems not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213365/discussion-between-tng-vit-dng-and-choroba).